# Confused on user and su in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, sudo, su

How could I run a script as a specific user (non-root)? As this?

`sudo su - john /usr/share/script.pl`  for user john?

Comment: `sudo -u john /usr/share/script.pl`

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro:But `sudo su - john` makes me `john`.So why it does not work for the script execution?

Comment: `su` is used to change to another user and `sudo` executes a command as a different user. They are different commands

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `-c` to `su` to execute a command. If `sudo` allows you to run the command, this should work:

```
sudo su - john -c "/usr/share/script.pl"
```

Keep in mind that by passing `-` to `su` your environment will be the same as if you had logged in, so if the script depends on environment variables (like current path) you may have to make adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

use the -c option like

```
sudo su - john -c "/usr/share/script.pl"
```

Or rather than defining the user like above you can define a cron job for the specific user using the following command

```
crontab -u john -e
```

then set the cron, it will add cron job for the specific user better then defining the user in a root cron

Answer (score 0):

Other answers give better answers to your specific question, here's some helpful explanation.

`su` = switch user

`sudo` = switch user and do X (with no extra options, the 'user' is 'root')

For most users `su` is not allowed without using `sudo`, which is meant to make the user think twice about what they're doing and usually to prompt again for password.